12oz gas needed for inflatable device. What gas is best and cylinder options do I have?
I am developing an inflatable safety product which will need to be inflated with a 12oz gas cylinder. I believe nitrogen is my best bet? If so, can nitrogen be stored in an aluminium tin? The reason I am asking is because I have seen manufactures of small camping stoves use butane gas cylinders which can be thrown away after use and replaced with another. That would be ideal. My other option is using cylinders used for paintball guns currently.
I am trying to make it "simple" for users of the product to be able to "refill" or replace the cylinder without effort. The device will only carry enough gas to inflate an inflatable once. The size of the inflatable is 1.2 m and 30 cm in diameter. It will be stored under a vehicle's seat or in the boot of a car. So hot conditions must be considered.
I would love to hear what gas is truly best and also what small cylinder I can use.

I recommend you buy the most similar inflatable device you can off the shelf (especially in terms of volume), and take that apart. My guess is that CO2 is most likely to be used, because it's liquid at pressure, and non-flamable.
